# deserializeUser in passport not getting called / session not working?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, passport.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to authenticate existing users with Stripe in my angularjs/ionic app and add their Stripe details to their existing account.

Passport works fine for local/social login, but with Stripe I was advised to use Sessions, and I don't think the sessions are recognising each other (can/should this be done without sessions?).

SerializeUser gets called fine, and once the user is authenticated "req.sessionStore.sessions" comes back and contains ALL the sessions so far, and I want to just get the corresponding/correct session. I think I might not be fully understanding the concept behind using a session, and I am looking for advice.

I set up my passport to use sessions like so:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,   
    cookie: {secure: false, maxAge: (4*60*60*1000)}
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

And my routes look like this

```
router.get('/auth/stripe', passport.authenticate('stripe'));
router.get('/auth/stripe/callback', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authorize('stripe', function(err, user, info) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8100/#/tab/create');
})(req, res, next)
});
```

My SerializeUser and DeserializeUser look like this

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    done(null, id);
});
```

Then my Stripe Passport strategy looks like this:

```
passport.use(new StripeStrategy(config.stripe, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, stripe_properties, done) {
    console.log(req.sessionStore.sessions);

    User.where({stripeId: stripe_properties.stripe_user_id}).fetch().then(function(user) {
        if(!user) {
            // TODO add stripe auth to users account
            var newUser = new User();
            newUser.set({
                stripeId: stripe_properties.stripe_user_id,
                email: 'test1'
            });
            newUser.save().then(function() {
                console.log('saved stripeId');
                return done(null, user);
            });
        }
        return done(null, user);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    });
}));
```

At the console.log point in my passport strategy there, the output for req.sessionStore.sessions looks like this:

```
{ jKu1zHufqvPqUHZhtb1Jp: '
{
"cookie": {
    "originalMaxAge": 14400000,
    "expires": "2016-03-23T18:11:28.009Z",
    "secure": false,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "path": "/"
},
"passport": {
    "user": {
        "id": 11,
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "email": "a@b.c",
        "password": ....
         etc
    }
}
}'}
```

and contains all of the sessions so far but I can't seem to access them(even if I could I know that this is not the right answer).

What am I missing both conceptually, and code wise to connect the session that gets sent off to Stripe, with the one that comes back?

How come my deserializeUser is never called?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Hey there :) Did you found a solution to this problem? I have exactly the same. Thanks

Comment: Didn't end up using sessions, couldn't get it to work. So used JWT instead @EtienneBaudoux